# HP laptop installed 14.04 from win 8.1. "The system is running in low-graphics mode". How do I fix this?

Tags: 14.04, graphics

I have HP laptop with Radeon graphics. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 from win 8.1. After the installation system restarts and it stuck with the message "The system is running in low-graphics mode". How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and install the drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx{,-amdcccle}{,-updates}
```

If those don't work, check whether or not HP supplies linux drivers for your model.  If so (unlikely), use them.  If not, download the drivers from http://support.amd.com/en-us/download and install manually (Check Google for instructions)